# C# How can I get from CompilerError instance exact text which caused the error

Tags: c#, compilation

Could you please  tell me how can I get from CompilerError instance exact text which caused the error.
Edited:

What about using

```
compilerError.FileName
```

and reading the file with text reader? I am trying to do so but it seems that Compiler doesn't create cs file that doesn't pass the compilation any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `CompilerError`? : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilererror.aspx

There are `FileName` and `Line` properties, that's the best you can get.

What are you compiling - is it entirely in-memory (CodeDOM)?

If so you can add code-line pragmas to your object model: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codelinepragma.aspx then you'll be able to link an error to a DOM element.

Or, you can compile from source, then you'll have the source code itself and can get the text from the line number.

Comment: It seems that Compiler doesn't create cs file that doesn't pass the compilation :(

Answer (score 0):

The best your going to get is the line number.